# Cubic bezier get $y$ as a function of $x$ (not $t$)

Tags: bezier-curve, spline

I'm trying to write a program to display curves.

I have 4 control points $ A, B, C $ and $ D $ and a value for $x$. From that, I want to find the value for $y$.

[image: example bezier curve]

### Where I've gotten so far

We can use De Casteljau's formula to describe a cubic bezier:

$$ 
P = (1-t)^3A+3(1-t)^2tB + 3(1-t)t^2C+t^2D
$$

Every point is a vector so

$$ 
x = (1-t)^3ax+3(1-t)^2tbx + 3(1-t)t^2cx+t^2dx
$$

If I solve this for $t$ I should be able to then plug that $t$ value into
$$ 
y = (1-t)^3ay+3(1-t)^2tby + 3(1-t)t^2cy+t^2dy
$$
To get my desired y value.

The problem is that I haven't found a way to solve this equation for t. I [plugged it into wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+t%2C+x+%3D+%281-t%29%5E3+*+a+%2B+3*%281-t%29%5E2+%2B+b+%2B+3%281-t%29+*+t%5E2+*+c+%2B+t%5E3+*d) but it seems to be only an approximation.

Is there a more precise / simpler way to achieve what I want?

EDIT: https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? Because, while you can do this (under certain constraints), it's going to be ugly - $y$ is not going to be a cubic in $x$, for example. If $y$ being a function of $x$ is a genuine constraint that you want to maintain, there are probably better splines to use than the general Bezier curve. (I don't know them, but if you clarify your ultimate goal, those who do will be better able to help you.)

Comment: this is used for keyframe interpolation in animation. You specify a start and end value and based on the spline you set, the in-between values are calculated. The x-axis is time  (in frames) and the y-axis is the value.

Comment: I guess people are used to using Bezier control points. Do you have a plan for how your interplator is going to behave if the control points lead to a curve that causes the $x$ value to increase, then decrease, then increase again, as you travel along the curve?

Comment: Good point, I just checked the curves [blender](https://www.blender.org/) uses and they behave slightly different from normal cubic bezier curves...

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/introduction.html#introduction

Comment: I found a few things, which were too much to fit into a comment. I dumped them in an answer below, even though they're not really an answer to your question. Good Luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116727/discussion-between-cubefox-and-jonathanz-supports-monicac).

Comment: If your purpose is to draw the curve, *do not* attempt to compute $y$ for different $x$'s.  Do vary $t$ and link the corresponding $(x,y)$ !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I"ll point you to another poster who seems to have started down the same road [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634960/ideal-spline-type-for-software-optimized-well-defined-interpolation-over-time-do), who seems not-so-happy with their decision.

I also found a good search term for what you want (where $x$ is time) is "easing curves", and the [MDN documentation about the CSS easing-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function) has some good details. The key thing I see there is that you can apply some easy-to-verify restrictions on your control points and you can be guaranteed to not have the "$x$ moving back and forth" problem.  If you could get your hands on that code you'd be golden.

There seems to be a Javascript implementation [here](https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing), and they talk about having to do a lot of clever work for the $x \leftrightarrow t$ problem that you are facing. They also claim that their code is used by React (!!) and Apple (!!!), so I'll suggest that this is one of those problems where your time is better spent getting someone else's code into your project than re-implementing it yourself. The underlying math question is still interesting, and follow that up if you're curious, but I wouldn't bother if I just wanted my project to move forward.

Comment: Just to note, the method here finds x the x->y mapping using newton's method. It doesn't provide an analytical solution

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram gives you the exact expressions, the same that Cardano would give. They can involve complex numbers. It is possible to implement them in a simpler form, by using intermediate variables.

Beware that depending on the positions of the control points, the value of $t$ might not be unique.

An alternative solution is to sample $t$ roughly, find an interval that contains your $x$ and use a few iterations of regula falsi.

---

Drawing the parametric curve $(x(t),y(t))$ is million times easier.

Comment: Drawing the curve is not the poster's ultimate goal.